# Diffusion Specular Normal

Tags: rendering, texturing, normal-map

as the title suggests, I'm looking for something that would turn meshes I made in Blender into a Specular, Diffused, and Normal Map, I know its not exactly a blender question but I know that there was a plug in that used to work really well as the aforementioned purpose, but that was ages ago in terms of Blender Version

Comment: are you talking about addons like [jbake](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fb5KBHuVHjc) ore [easy bake](https://github.com/leukbaars/EasyBake)?

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about baking textures. To do so, you have two options. If you have a texture using image textures, there already is a "bake" option in cycles' render panel. If you have a procedural (BSDF) setup, you'll need to use an addon like https://blenderartists.org/t/principled-baker-bake-pbr-textures-with-a-few-clicks/1102187